# Has Perseverance fired up its RIMFAX yet?

Tags: mars, perseverance, radar, ground-penetrating-radar

[image: PIA24048: Testing RIMFAX for NASA's Perseverance Rover]

[PIA24048: Testing RIMFAX for NASA's Perseverance Rover](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA24048)

> Original Caption Released with Image:
>
> A test model of the RIMFAX instrument — aboard the trailer behind the snow mobile — undergoes field testing in Svalbard, Norway.
>
> The first ground-penetrating radar set on the surface of Mars, [RIMFAX](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/instruments/rimfax/) can provide a highly detailed view of subsurface structures down to at least 30 feet (10 meters) underground. In doing so, the instrument will reveal hidden layers of geology and help find clues to past environments on Mars, especially those with conditions necessary for supporting life.

**Question:** Has Perseverance fired up its ground penetrating radar RIMFAX yet?